# How can I display a text file within a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, working-directory

Im trying to display a text file in a directory within the folder my script is in. I tried things like:

```
mypath=`realpath $0`
FILE="$realpath/Folder/Text.txt"
cat $FILE
```

And

```
FILE="$PWD/Folder/Text.txt"
cat $FILE
```

but they include the name of the file instead of just the its running from. I also want it to work with symbolic links.

Comment: Where did you define $realpath? The second should work perfectly... What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please edit your post because the question is not a question.

Comment: I forgot to define `$realpath`.
When I tried the second, I got this:
`cat: /home/ely/License/gpl-3.0.txt: No such file or directory`
when the real directory is
`/home/ely/Desktop/Minecraft Installer Package/License/gpl-3.0.txt` @StefanLindenberg

Comment: That last comment was ment for @FakeRainBrigand . Also I didn't think I needed to difine it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat "$(dirname -- "$0")/Folder/Text.txt"
```

That is, send the file `Text.txt` in the directory `Folder` below *the directory where this script is located* to standard output.

This will work with symlinks. And yes, all the quotes are significant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cat "./Folder/Text.txt"
```

the period denotes the current folder you are in.  a double period "../Folder/Text.txt" denotes a folder up in the directory tree.